# Pyspark Join two dataframes, df1 has lookup data and df2 has array find respective values from lookup keys and create array of values in df2

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

### Pyspark dataframe API

Given two dataframes A and B, where:

##### Dataframe A:

| id | names |
| --- | --- |
| abc-2 | John |
| bbb-1 | peter |
| def-y | kim |
| xyz-0 | brad |

##### Dataframe B:

| id_list |
| --- |
| "abc-2","bbb-1" |
| "abc-2" |
| "abc-2","xyz-0" |

The final dataframe should be:

##### Dataframe B:

| id_list | users |
| --- | --- |
| "abc-2","bbb-1" | john,peter |
| "abc-2" | john |
| "abc-2,xyz-0" | john,brad |

How can I use Pyspark dataframe API to achieve this outcome?

Answer (score 0):

- Exploding the "id_list" column in df_b by splitting it on commas
  using split(col("id_list"), ",") and then using explode() to generate
  one row for each element resulting from the split.  The exploded
  elements are stored in a new column called "id".
- Left join between df_a and the modified df_b on the "id"    column
  using df_a.id == df_b.id.  The result is stored in joined_df.
- Grouping joined_df by the "id_list" column and aggregating the
  "names" column using collect_list("names").  The resulting
  aggregation is stored in a new column called "users" using
  alias("users").

Code:

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split, explode, collect_list, concat_ws
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data_a = [("abc-2", "John"), ("bbb-1", "Peter"), ("def-y", "Kim"), ("xyz-0", "Brad")]
df_a = spark.createDataFrame(data_a, ["id", "names"])
data_b = [("abc-2,bbb-1",), ("abc-2",), ("abc-2,xyz-0",)]
df_b = spark.createDataFrame(data_b, ["id_list"])
 
df_b = df_b.withColumn("id", explode(split(col("id_list"), ",")))
joined_df = df_b.join(df_a, df_a.id == df_b.id, "left")
final_df = joined_df.groupby("id_list").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list("names")).alias("users"))
final_df = final_df.withColumn("users", final_df["users"].cast("string"))
final_df.display(truncate=False)
```

[image]